# Displaying foreign characters from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a MySQL database that has certain unconventional character stored in it such as `é`, `▲`, `█▓░✌`, `ᄼᄽᄾ` etc.

When I query them from the DB and attempt to display them on the webpage they simply show up as a `?` even though I have the following metatag in place: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and the DB collation is set to `utf8_general_ci`

How can I display these characters properly? Do they need to be stored in a different way inside the DB?

note: the characters are readable inside the DB, but not when I display them on the page.

## The Solution

Adding this into my dbconnect file solved my problem.

```
/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
```

Comment: You need to run these queries before reading data from mysql `SET CHARACTER SET utf8; SET NAMES utf8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this issue is to call the query "SET NAMES utf8" before accessing your utf8 charecters from DB

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm actually using MySQLi so after a little investigating I am now using the code I editing into my original post and it works great!